# Scope of variables inside switch case statement in Java

Tags: java, string, switch-statement

I have the following code, my question is how can we persist the value of String A and B and use it in another case statement for comparing it.

```
String A = null;
String B = null;
Switch(key) {

   case “ABC”:
     A = “Hello”;
   break;
   case “XYZ”:
     B = “Hi”;
    break;
   case “compare”:
      A.equals(B); //Exception here as A and B are nulls.
```

Can anyone please guide me here as I’am really confused with the variable scope in switch case.

Comment: `A` and `B` will be null unless you first assign values to them.  This would occur only if this `switch` statement was in a loop and in previous iterations it executed the first and second cases.  It is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: And you'd have to declare the variables outside of said loop.

Comment: Use case looks like this -- Initially, first two switch cases executes and then it would go into the third case where it should compare String A and String B and print true/false depending on the logic. My question is how can we persist values of String A and String B ? Currently, when the program enters third switch-case (compare) after going into "ABC" and "XYZ" the Value of String A and B are nulls as it is again getting initialized to null. I know why it is getting assigned to null, but want the solution how to initialize A and B in switch case to persist the values.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is not related to the lifetime of the switch-case block or objects `A` and `B`. The `String.equals()` method throws a `NullPointerException` because you are assigning `null` values to objects `A` and `B`. If you want `String` objects to not get this error, initialize `String` objects to empty; for example `String city = "";`. If you want objects `A` or `B` to be compared after a value is assigned and the program to be redirected to another control, you can review the example below. *If there is a different problem, try to explain the problem by drawing a flowchart.*

```java
public class HelloWorld
{
    public static boolean Compare(String s1, String s2)
    {
        if(s1.equals(s2))
            return true;
        return false;
    }
    
     public static void main(String []args)
     {
        String A = "", B = "Hello", key = "ABC";

        switch(key) 
        {
           case "ABC": /* assignment and comparison */
                A = "Hello";
                
                if(Compare(A, B))
                { /* program can be directed according to the situation. */}
                else
                { /* program can be directed according to the situation. */}
                break;
           case "XYZ": /* assignment and comparison */
                B = "Hi";
                
                if(Compare(A, B))
                { /* program can be directed according to the situation. */}
                else
                { /* program can be directed according to the situation. */}
                break;
           case "compare": /* just comparison */
                if(Compare(A, B))
                { /* program can be directed according to the situation. */}
                else
                { /* program can be directed according to the situation. */}
                break; 
        }
        System.out.printf("A: %s B: %s", A, B);
    }
}
```

Comment: Here, value of key is determined by another logic, so even if I initialize strings as empty, I am still not able to persist String A and B values

Comment: I updated the answer.  If there is a different problem, try to explain the problem by drawing a flowchart.

Comment: Use case looks like this -- Initially, first two switch cases executes and then it would go into the third case where it should compare String A and String B and print true/false depending on the logic. My question is how can we persist values of String A and String B ? Currently, when the program enters third switch-case (compare) after going into "ABC" and "XYZ" the Value of String A and B are nulls as it is again getting initialized to null. I know why it is getting assigned to null, but want the solution how to initialize A and B in switch case to persist the valueS

Answer (score 0):

In your Switch-case statement you're comparing whatever is in *key* with the different *cases*, proceeding as follows:

- is *key* equals to "ABC"? then A = "Hello"
- is *key* equals to "XYZ"? then B = "Hi"
- is *key* equals to "compare"? then compare A and B (which so far, are nulls)

Note, that if your code reaches the last case statement, means it skipped the other two, so A and B are nulls. Also, your code is assuming that *key* will have the next possible values: "ABC", "XYZ", or "compare", and if *key* does not have any of those values, your program will do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

> Can anyone please guide me here as I am really confused with the variable scope in switch case.

The following are for a classic (Java 11 or earlier) `switch` statement.

- Variables declared outside of the switch block are "in scope" inside the switch block.
- Variables declared inside of the switch block are "in scope" inside the switch block.  The scope starts at the point of the declaration and continues for the remainder of the switch block.

  Thus, a variable declared in one case will be in scope in following cases if the cases "drop through".

So, in your example, `A` and `B` are in scope before the `switch`, within the `switch`, and after it.  But if they were declared within the `switch` they wouldn't be in scope after the `switch`.

---

The initialization of variables declared within a `switch` is governed by the normal rules.  Explicit initializers are executed when the declaration is encountered, and variables must be definitely initialized before they are used.

```
switch (num) {
case 1: 
    int a = 1;
    // No break ...
case 2:
    System.out.println(a); // ERROR - not definitely initialized.
}
System.out.println(a);     // ERROR - not in scope.
```

In the above, `a` is in scope in the second switch case, but will not be initialized in *all* paths to its `println` statement.

---

As @Sercan [notes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70600933/139985), the reason for your NPE is nothing to do with scopes, or definite initialization.  The actual problem is that the execution path that your code takes in the `"compare"` case does not assign a non-null value to `A`.  (Or `B` either.  But the non-nullness of `B` should not cause an NPE.)